# wix bootstrapper seems to uninstall packages simultaneously

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, chain

I have a boostrapper with 7 package groups in the chain.  Some of the packages use Exe packages and some msi packages. The packagegroups withe exepackages have two packages:  one to use in install and one in uninstall.  The sourcefile and uninstallcommand for uninstall are batch files with parameters.  The packagegroups using msipackages do nothing special.

During install the packagegroups are processed sequentially in 1, 2, 3,... order defined by their order of appearance in the chain.

During uninstall the packagegroups are processed only roughly in the the reverse order of their appearance in the chain; the difference being that multiple windows may appear on the screen simultaneously each reflecting the uninstall of one element in the chain as though more than one packagegroup is being uninstalled at the same time.

Its not clear what is going on.  Any thoughts?  I am wondering if the completion of nested batch scripts (cmd files) is signalling a termination that the bootstrapper is interpreting to mean that an packagegroup uninstall is complete and so initiates the next uninstall?

Comment: There should be a log in %temp% created by your bootstrapper. It will show you what it detects as installed and what it plans to do with all the packages. It would be very useful to us and probably you as well to take a look at this/include it in the question. It is also weird to have two `<ExePackage>` entries for the same exe; Could you include a set of `<ExePackage>` tags you have in your bootstrapper?

Comment: I was wondering about that (multiple <ExePackage>'s) too.  The PackageGroup Element allows n>1.  And it clearly works on install.  But its worth exploring and ez to do too.

Comment: Yes.  I broke the PackageGroups up so they only included one <ExePackage> each and updated and re-organized the bundle.wsx file and now it uninstalls smoothly as expected (and hoped for).